# does updating .net version when compiling affects client dependencies?

Tags: c#, .net, target-framework

If I update from .net 4.5 to .net 4.8 when i compile my project. Does that introduce a risk that the clients cant run the dlls?
Do all users have to upgrade to .net 4.8 on their machines or are the .net version backwards compatible? They have all been able to run the app when it was compiled with .net 4.5.

What im trying to ask is if i risk that some clients wont be able to run the app by upgrading the Target Framework when building it.
This is from 4.5 to 4.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that introduce a risk that the clients cant run the dlls?

Yes

> Do all users have to upgrade to .net 4.8 on their machines

Yes, if they do not already have it.

> are the .net version backwards compatible?

Yes, they are *backwards* compatible, meaning a user with .net 4.8 can run programs written for .net 4.5 with no issue. Not the other way around.

> What i'm trying to ask is if i risk that some clients wont be able to run the app by upgrading the Target Framework when building it.

They *should* have .net 4.8 installed since it is bundled with windows 10 1903 and later. See [versions and dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies). All older versions of windows 10 is end of life. The only exceptions are windows server 2019/2016.

Even if your client lacks .Net 4.8, windows should simply ask if they want to install .net 4.8, so it should be very easy to do as long as the users have permission to install things on their computers.